# How to use specific .swiftlint.yml?? swiftlint is hiting it is on root path.

Tags: ios, swiftlint

How to use specific .swiftlint.yml??

swiftlint is hiting it is on root path.
Even I put another .swiftlint.yml in child path.

I can see below description on swiftlint github.

## Each file will be linted using the configuration file that is in its directory or at the deepest level of its parent directories. Otherwise the root configuration will be used.

I have used --config option, but it doesn't works...

Answer (score -1):

You can download the `SwiftLint.pkg` file from [SwiftLint Github](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases), and install on your system. Then put your `.yml` file at your root code folder.

Then in Build Phases add the below script,

```
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
swiftlint
else
echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Please refer the screenshots,
[image: image1][image: image2]